# Bootstrap-star-rating set default stars

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using [Bootstrap-star-rating](http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating), here is my code :

```
<input id="input-id" type="number" class="rating" min=1 max=10 step=2 data-size="lg" data-rtl="true">
```

```js
$("#input-id").rating();
```

I'd like to set a number of stars selected by default. Right now there is 5 stars shown, whereas I want to show it with 2 stars selected by default. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
$('#input-id').rating({'update': 2,
                       'showCaption':false,
                       'showClear':false
                     });
```

Comment: It works but how can i put these property : showCaption:false,showClear:false ...