# MVC rating Bootstrap Jquery unselect stars selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing an `MVC` Application with `Rating Bootstrap`.

```
<input id="input-21b" type="number" class="rating" data-show-clear="false" data-show-caption="false" min=0 max=5 step=1 data-glyphicon="false" data-size="sm">
```

I have also define this...in order to know how many start has been clicked.

```html
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#input-21b").on("rating.change", function (event, value, caption) {
            $('#hdfRatingValue').val(value);

    });
```

I have a hidden input to keep the starts selected.

It Works fine...

When User clicks "OK" buttom, a `Ajax` function is called to save the rating.

What I need is to `UnSelect` the starts selected via `Jquery`....

I have try

```html
  $('#input-21b').rating({
            'update': 0,
            'showCaption': false,
            'showClear': false
        });
```

Ais it says is [Bootstrap-star-rating set default stars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429408/bootstrap-star-rating-set-default-stars)

But Nothing happend. I also Include

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--  required libraries  -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-star-rating/4.0.1/css/star-rating.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-star-rating/4.0.1/js/star-rating.min.js"></script>
```

Still nothing happend.

Is that Posible?

Thanks

Comment: Is your real code missing the `$` from in front of the `('#input-21b').rating()` call or is that a copy and paste error?

Comment: It was my mistake.. I added but function does not do anything... thanks

Comment: If it's just a typo in the question, and not your real code, fix the question and then have a look at the answer from @gaetanoM below, as it's likely you haven't included the library code correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried But Nothing happend:
>
> ```
> $('#input-21b').rating({
>     'update': 0,
>     'showCaption': false,
>     'showClear': false
> });
> ```

[update](http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating#usage) is a method and you cannot use it at initialization. Moreover, you don't need initialization because you specified all attributes in the HTML.

If you want to use that method you must write:

```
$('#input-21b').rating('update', 0).trigger('rating.change');
```

But you can also directly [reset](http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating#methods) the rating to its initial value:

```
$('#input-21b').rating('reset').trigger('rating.change');
```

Why do you need to [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the event *rating.change*? Because in this way you can execute your related event handler (i.e.: copy the value to your hidden field).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#input-21b").on("rating.change", function (event, value, caption) {
      $('#hdfRatingValue').val(value);
  });
  $('button').on('click', function(e) {
      //$('#input-21b').rating('update', 0).trigger('rating.change');
      $('#input-21b').rating('reset').trigger('rating.change');
  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--  required libraries  -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-star-rating/4.0.1/css/star-rating.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-star-rating/4.0.1/js/star-rating.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input-21b">Rating:</label>
            <input id="input-21b" type="number" class="rating" data-show-clear="false" data-show-caption="false"
                   min=0 max=5 step=1 data-glyphicon="false" data-size="sm">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input-21b">Rating Value:</label>
            <input id="hdfRatingValue" type="text">
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Reset rating</button>
    </form>
</div>
```